# Ternary operator throws error while specified values honor the type definition

Tags: c#

Ternary operator throws casting error, can not implicitly convert from type int to short:

```
short step;
int count = 0;
step = (count == 0) ? 1:2;
```

As 1 & 2 are pre-specified values and fits the definition of type short, not sure why compiler throws error.

Comment: Because you are possibly going to lose information by converting from a integer to a short so explicit cast is necessary.

Comment: The right hand side is not a constant expression implicitly convertible to short, so this is disallowed without a cast. Though you might consider just using an integer to store `step` unless you have a specific reason for it to be a short.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen an explanation as to why c# has not `short` literals? VB has them. About once every year or two I scratch my head about this and ask why. Of course, that head-scratching frequency may be the answer

Comment: Ternary operator will always evaluate True/False, even though it involves variables. Ideally compiler should only look for the values 1 & 2, which is the result of ternary operation. As 1 & 2 are valid Short values, shouldn't throw a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this expression:

```
(count == 0) ? 1:2
```

**The compiler must evaluate the expression on its own merits**, without any regard for the variable type receiving the result. Looking at this alone, it's clearly going to produce an `int`.

The `short` type is smaller than `int`, so the assignment has a potential to lose information; this is a *narrowing conversion*. Of course, you and I both know `1` and `2` are perfectly safe here, but the compiler doesn't get to look at values; at compile time, the code is evaluated only in terms of **types**. And since an `int` won't automatically fit in a `short`, you have to cast.

You could also do this to avoid casting:

```
short a=1,b=2;
int count = 0;
short step = (count == 0) ? a:b;
```

Going the other direction and widening to a `long`, you could define the literals using an `L` suffix:

```
long step = (count == 0)?1L:2L;
```

But I'm not aware of a similar mechanism to force a `short` literal.

Comment: There is still more depth to the question, if you can answer it would be great! There is no compile error if you do a string comparison `short step = ("1" == "2") ? 1 : 2;` or even just a hard-coded bool, like: `short step = (true) 1 : 2;`. So why does it become an issue when an `int` comparison is used in the ternary condition, since that evaluation has nothing to do with the type being assigned?

Comment: @RufusL Change `"1"` to a variable, and suddenly it fails again. Apparently, if **everything** is a constant, the entire expression also reduces to a constant and the compiler will make that optimization.

Comment: Yes! I just figured that out myself. Thank you! :)

Comment: Ternary operator will always evaluate True/False, even though it involves variables. Ideally compiler should only look for the values 1 & 2, which is the result of ternary operation. As 1 & 2 are valid Short values, shouldn't throw a compile error.

Comment: @VishwajeetSawant Again, the compiler evaluates the expression without knowing it will be assigned to a short. The language spec says those are `int` literals, so int is what you get, and and `int` to `short` is a narrowing version that requires an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast the values, converting this

```
step = (count == 0) ? 1:2;
```

to

```
step = (short)((count == 0) ? 1:2);
```

why? the ternary operator is returning directly an `int`, and `step` is `short` value, so you have to cast the type so it knows that the returning value is `short` type and not `int`

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/type-conversion:

> Narrowing conversions involve the creation of a new value from the
>   value of an existing type that has either a greater range or a larger
>   member list than the target type. Because a narrowing conversion can
>   result in a loss of data, compilers often require that the conversion
>   be made explicit through a call to a conversion method or a casting
>   operator. That is, the conversion must be handled explicitly in
>   developer code.

So as I commented, you are asking the compiler to do a narrowing conversion and you could possible lose information. If you switch the types of step and count you will not get an error because in this case you would then be performing a widening conversion.